# Issue while executing asynchronous method inside a nested loop in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have call an asynchronous function inside a  nested loop like below

```
var queue = new Queue<ExchangeEmailInformation>(mailInformation);
var currentQueue = queue.ToList();
foreach (var exchangeEmailInformation in currentQueue)
{
    ExchangeEmailInformation information = exchangeEmailInformation;
    foreach (var queueList in exchangeEmailInformation.Attachment)
    {
        Attachment attachment = queueList;
        information.FileName = attachment.Name;
        var emailId = information.Sender.Split('@');
        information.UserAlias = emailId[0];
        information.FileSize = attachment.Size;
        AddAttachmentAsync(information);

    }

}

private static void AddAttachmentAsync(ExchangeEmailInformation information)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        AddAttachment(information.UserAlias, information.EngagementName,
                        information.DocumentTransferId.ToString(), information.FileName,
                        information.FileSize.ToString(), information.ActivityName)).ContinueWith(
                            task => OnComplete(task, information), TaskContinuationOptions.None);
}

static void AddAttachment(string userAlias, string engagementName, string documentTranferId, string fileName, string fileSize,string activityName)
{
    Console.Writeline(fileName);

}

In the exchange information collection has one record. In these collection there is another property called Attachment which type is AttachmentCollection which contain two attachments. After calling the method AddAttachmentAsync like above asynchronously the
```

results printed is

- SecondAttachment.txt
- SecondAttachment.txt.

showing the second attachment only(Incorrect result).

Then i try to execute the same as Synchronously like below.

```
private static void AddAttachmentAsync(ExchangeEmailInformation information)
{
    AddAttachment(information.UserAlias, information.EngagementName,
                    information.DocumentTransferId.ToString(), information.FileName,
                    information.FileSize.ToString(), information.ActivityName);


}
```

The result is

- FirstAttachment.txt
- SecondAttachment.txt

showing correct results as i wanted

How can i fix these issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line of the second foreach(), you must make a copy of 'information' and pass the copy to AddAttachmentAsync. (That is, a copy of all the data - not just a copy of the object reference.)

What's happening is that the 'information' object you're passing to AddAttachmentAsync() is being changed before AddAttachmentAsync() has returned.

In general, when designing classes such as ExchangeEmailInformation that are used for multithreaded stuff, you should make them immutable - then it's impossible for this particular  kind of thing to happen. (In my opinion, you should make ALL POD ("plain old data") classes immutable.)

Comment: Like I said, make a copy of the contents of the 'information' object and pass that copy to AddAttachmentAsync.

Comment: Like this  ExchangeEmailInformation tempInformation = information;
                                    Attachment attachment = queueList;

                                    tempInformation.FileName = attachment.Name;
                                    var emailId = tempInformation.Sender.Split('@');
                                    tempInformation.UserAlias = emailId[0];
                                    tempInformation.FileSize = attachment.Size;
                                    AddAttachmentAsync(tempInformation);

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. I'd probably write a separate method just to make a copy of an ExchangeEmailInformation object for clarity, but what you posted should work.

Comment: @JEMI No, that is not correct. You are only creating a new reference to the same object!

Comment: @JEMI Start with this: `var tempInformation = new ExchangeEmailInformation();`

Comment: I have write code like you said and pass this tempInformation to the AddAttachmentAsyn.But It's not working

Comment: Sorry I misread your post there. Where you say  ExchangeEmailInformation tempInformation = information, you need to say  ExchangeEmailInformation tempInformation = new ExchangeEmailInformation(), and then the rest of the code should be the same.

Answer (score 5):

`information` is a **reference type** object declared outside of the nested loop. You are passing this object to your `AddAttachmentAsync` method, but before waiting for it to complete (or even start processing the `Task`), you are already modifying `information` in the next iteration.

You should make a copy of `information` before sending it to the asynchronous method.

**Edit** as Marc points out this should be a **new object** with copied values, not just a new reference to the same object.

Comment: I know it is what you meant, but just to expand for the OP : you need a new **object**, copying the *values* from the old one - not just a copy of the *variable* `information`, which would just be a copy of the same reference with the same value pointing to the same object, with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You have modified closure on `information`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're using the same `ExchangeEmailInformation` instance, `information`, for every inner `foreach` loop iteration in a single outer `foreach` loop iteration; you update properties in that instance for the next asynchronous call before the previous call has a chance to read its values.

In the asynchronous case, the order of events is

1. Populate `information` for call 1
2. Populate `information` for call 2
3. Execute call 1
4. Execute call 2

so by the time call 1 executes, `information` already contains the data for call 2. In the synchronous case, this doesn't happen; the loop can't continue until call 1 is done executing.

I think the best way to fix this would be to stop *changing* `information` and to pass the three used-to-be-changed fields in as separate parameters. (Actually it looks like `UserAlias` only needs to be updated once, so you don't need to pass it separately. Note also that taking a copy of `queueList` isn't necessary if you do this.)

```
ExchangeEmailInformation information = exchangeEmailInformation;
var emailId = information.Sender.Split('@');
information.UserAlias = emailId[0];

foreach (var queueList in exchangeEmailInformation.Attachment)
{
    AddAttachmentAsync(information, queueList.Name, queueList.Size);
}

// and modify AddAttachmentAsync to use these two parameters too
```

An alternative would be to take a copy of `queueList` as you were doing, and then pass both `information` *and that copy* into `AddAttachmentAsync` and pull the parameters from each of the two as appropriate:

```
ExchangeEmailInformation information = exchangeEmailInformation;
var emailId = information.Sender.Split('@');
information.UserAlias = emailId[0];

foreach (var queueList in exchangeEmailInformation.Attachment)
{
    var attachment = queueList;
    AddAttachmentAsync(information, attachment);
}

// and modify AddAttachmentAsync to pull properties from the right parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers which correctly assess that you need to create an instance of `information` for each thread I would make another suggestion. I notice you have created a call `AddAttachment` and though currently it merely makes a `Console.Write` I imagine eventually you will be accessing a list and adding an instance of the result to this list. This will create an unnecessary situation of accessing a shared resource.

Instead of having each thread be responsible for adding it's result to the list it is much simpler to have the master thread create an instance of an object with a reference type property and pass this to the thread. This way the thread already has a location to store it's result and since it's not a shared resource you don't have to worry about synching.

Here's a very basic example. Obviously you'll have to alter it slightly to your needs.

```
class Result
{
   public object Data { get; set; }
}

List<Work> WorkToDo = // Some population call
List<Result> Results = new List<Result>();
foreach (Work Item in WorkToDo)
{
    Result Result = new Result();
    Results.Add(Result);
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => { Result.Data = "Hello World."; });
}
```

Again this is just to point out that just because you want all your results compiled into a list or array of some kind doesn't mean you need to share access to the list. Letting the parent thread handle all that can greatly simplify your algorithm.